# printing a statement based on a user input python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am ask the user to specify air or car and then the program should print "book air travel" if the user says air and "book a car or hotel" if the user says car. But it seems when I put car it is still printing "book air travel". What am I missing?

```
travel=raw_input("What type of travel is required Air or Car")
if travel == "Air" or "air":
    print "book air travel"
elif travel== "Car" or "car":
    print "book a car or hotel"
```

Comment: It is amazing how many times this question gets asked.

Comment: It reminded me of sth :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this

```
travel=raw_input("What type of travel is required Air or Car").lower()
if travel == "air":
    print "book air travel"
elif travel== "car":
    print "book a car or hotel"
```

Make it lower case from the start to avoid having multiple checks.